# Rails fails to start on docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to setup my rails application to run using docker. It keeps crashing with `Could not find rake-12.3.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)`

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.6.1

RUN apt-get update -yqq && \
  apt-get install -yqq --no-install-recommends \
  nodejs \
  nano

COPY Gemfile* /usr/src/app/
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
RUN bundle install
RUN gem install foreman
RUN gem install rake -v 12.3.2

COPY . /usr/src/app/

CMD [ "bin/rails", "s", "-b", "0.0.0.0" ]
```

#### .docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:10.3-alpine'
    volumes:
      - 'postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data'
    env_file:
      - '.env'

  redis:
    image: 'redis:4.0-alpine'
    command: redis-server --requirepass yourpassword
    volumes:
      - 'redis:/data'

  rails:
    depends_on:
      - 'postgres'
      - 'redis'
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - '.:/usr/src/app'
    env_file:
      - '.env'

volumes:
  redis:
  postgres:
```

#### config/boot.rb

```
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../Gemfile', __dir__)

require 'bundler/setup' # Set up gems listed in the Gemfile.
require 'bootsnap/setup' if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /darwin/
```

#### log

```
rails_1     | /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:91:in `block in materialize': Could not find rake-12.3.2 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `map!'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/spec_set.rb:85:in `materialize'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:170:in `specs'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:237:in `specs_for'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/definition.rb:226:in `requested_specs'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb:108:in `block in definition_method'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/runtime.rb:20:in `setup'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/bundler/setup.rb:20:in `<top (required)>'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
rails_1     |   from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
rails_1     |   from /usr/src/app/config/boot.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
rails_1     |   from bin/rails:3:in `require_relative'
rails_1     |   from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Few days ago, i had the same issue. `gem list | grep rake` and delete useless version, but also better deleting `gemfile.lock`, and bundle new one. Since, i was dealing with ruby 2.3.0, i had to install manually old version of rake in gem file*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to pull down the current latest release of rake. You can remove the version declaration and let it auto resolve in this case.

Any reason this dependency is not in your Gemfile? Also, the rails app you are starting will include a dependency to rake. You should not need to install rake.

Comment: I added that line trying the fix the error, but it didn't help.

Comment: Removing it fixed it. Must have the way I was caching the gems previously